# How to parse json data received from a jQuery ajax call in php

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm calling a php script (getNum.php) via ajax after creating an object and using jquery.json to turn
it to json. Now i want to handle the object on the php side. 
`print_r($_POST['data'])` doesn't work nor anything else i've tried.

This is my code:

```
// create object
    var bing= new Object();
    bing.id = 99;
    bing.nameList = getBingList();

    //create pdf
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "getNum.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: $.toJSON(bing),
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        window.location = "generateBing.php?num="+data
    }

    });
```

Comment: what file do you have the `print_r` statement in?  your page that contains the javascript or the page that is called by the javascript (generateBing.php)?

Comment: Why do you have `dataType: "html"`?

Comment: generateBing.php isn't related. getNum.php contains the print_r code

Comment: @Shedal because the getNum.php script returns html

Comment: How about `print_r($_POST)`? I guess it will contain two keys: `id` and `nameList`.

Comment: @jedwards no..getNum.php is the one getting the ajax call

Comment: He's saying the data sent in `bing` needs to be accessed somehow in `getNum.php` and he doesn't know how. This isn't related to `generateBing.php`

Comment: @Shedal print_r($_POST) generates an Array()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `print_r($_POST['data'])` to show the content, you'll need to send it as "data" as well.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getNum.php",
    data: {data: $.toJSON(bing)},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        window.location = "generateBing.php?num="+data
    }
});
```

Otherwise you have to do `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: I doubt jQuery will handle posting hierarchical data.

Comment: You'll want to remove contentType, since this way stops it from being application/json.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - removed both, as they are normally not needed. If it's a valid json object, jQuery will figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are posting a JSON object directly, there is no argument name for $_POST. You'll need to read the raw contents of the POST request. Try this:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print_r($data);
```

Comment: There, should work now. As you mentioned, the contentType effects all of this. Since you had JSON content-type, PHP cannot automatically process it. It is up to you to read the request data and process it into PHP vars.